# videogular on android device

Tags: ionic-framework, videogular

I am trying to get a video to play from an ionic app using videogular. The video is stored locally on my device within the app in a vids folder. I have grabbed the actual videogular.mp4 file which so the local path is vids/videogular.mp4. In the config if I use the url to the site :

$sce.trustAsResourceUrl(http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.mp4) 
the vide plays fine, but if I point to the local directory :

$sce.trustAsResourceUrl('/vids/videogular.mp4') the file wont play. I have also tried using the cordova.file.applicationDirectory + vids/videogular.mp4 to get the local url, that doesnt play either. I have also tried window.requestFileSystem to get the local url and it gives me the following url:

file:///data/data/com.ionicframework.videogularapp818380/files/files/vids/videogular.mp4

but this doesnt work either. Does anyone know how to do this? The android device is using android 4.4.2. I am having such problems trying to play video files I am wanting to bundle in the app so the user doesnt have to stream over an internet connection. I want to be able to use the ionic app on android and ios but have been testing on an android device.

Answer (score 1):

I found part of the problem was the file format. I had to make sure the mp4 files were encoded H.264/MPEG-4 AVC Video, seems some devices have issues with just  work with just any mp4 conversion. For anyone else having issues that might help you.